# How to increase ODBC Command Timeout When Using SQL Server Import/Export Tool

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, import

I am using ODBC driver to transfer data from Postgres to SQL Server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-postgresql-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16

The issue is that some tables are throwing,

> Error 0xc0047062: Data Flow Task 1: System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException
> (0x80131937): ERROR [57014] ERROR: canceling statement due to
> statement timeout; Error while executing the query    at
> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,
> RetCode retcode)    at
> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments,
> SQL_API odbcApiMethod)    at
> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method, Boolean needReader)    at
> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at
> System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.PreExecute()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100
> wrapper) (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I am getting this error after 30 seconds. I have increased statement_timeout in postgres and set `Command Timeout` in the connection string but no help. Is there is a way to increase OdbcCommand.CommandTimeout when using SQL Server Import feature?

Comment: Removed my other answer as it was wrong. Does this one work? "Query Timeout=60"

Comment: Look in the PostgreSQL server log file to see it reports the error differently or with more info.

Comment: @Peter it worked thanks a lot

Comment: Great, Í've changed the answer to the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you change the `Command Timeout` to `Query Timeout=`

Comment: Tried both and not working. BTW, its OdbcConnection and OdbcCommand.